# What is the black floating ghost?

Tags: antichamber

I have noticed a black floating ghost in the room adjacent to mine. It passed through just above the yellow gun. What is it? Is it a bug?

[image: The black floating ghost]

Comment: While I do not know what it is exactly, I find it hard to believe it to be a bug - after all, I've seen it in two or three places and it vividly moves, casting a shadow as it goes. Seems more like some kind of 'darkness' to me.

Comment: Smoke monster from Lost? I would agree with @mabako that it's part of the game, not a bug.

Comment: It's certainly not a bug. It appears very predictable when you enter that room before you got the yellow gun. I didn't encounter that thing again so far, but I haven't completed the game yet.

Comment: If you're looking for meaning in the things that happen, you're going to have a very hard time with this game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug. You will encounter that... thing... again at a later point in the game.

> When you encounter it again, you have to follow it solving various puzzles. When you got it, you have to suck it in with your gun. This brings you to the final area of the game. There you have to bring it to a black cube and release it. This completes the game.

Regarding what it actually *is* and what it's *meaning* is... well, I guess that's up to your own interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it foreshadows what you need to do to progress.  Well, actually, it foreshadows where you need to travel, in order to progress.  Actually accomplishing that travel is whole other story...