# What is 4D about Antichamber?

Tags: antichamber

I have now completed Antichamber, and I am wondering what makes it 4D, as one does not take advantage of the fourth dimension in any way. I get the impression the the 4D component is referring to the chamber changing from different angles and changing whenever you look away, but this is a basic misunderstanding of what the fourth dimension is.

Can anyone offer insight into this matter?

Comment: What would you consider being the fourth dimension, *time*? Because if you go visit those fancy "4D cinemas", their concept of the fourth dimension is *sprinkling people with water* and *shaking their seats* (along with 3D vision). You may want to consult [this wikipedia article about the four-dimensional space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-dimensional_space).

Comment: Where does Antichamber claim to be "4D"?  And even if it did, what would that even mean?  And what would you expect it to mean instead?  In any case, voting to close - this appears to be a discussion question, which are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @Nolonar The interpretation of 4D by those cinemas is wrong. Additionally, regardless of whether the fourth dimension as featured in Antichamber is spatial or temporal, Antichamber features neither.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft When you Google "antichamber", many of the reviews cite it as 4D. For example, Ars Technica says "Antichamber is a mind-bending, four-dimensional journey".

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Additionally, I am trying to see if the reviewers are wrong, or if Antichamber is actually 4D, and this is thus intended as a standard Q&A-type question. However, I understand how it may be interpreted as or may turn into a discussion question.

Comment: I would assume that they were using "four-dimensional" to describe the fact that the entire game is non-Euclidean in 3D space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's at least one explicitly 4-dimensional concept floating around in Antichamber, and reaching it is arguably the goal of the game.

Just keep in mind that, analogous to the way that the shadow of a 3-dimensional object is a 2-dimensional object, [the shadow of a 4-dimensional object is a 3-dimensional object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-dimensional_space#Shadows).

[Sound familiar?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103459/what-is-the-black-floating-ghost)

Comment: I was unaware that the "final objective" was 4D; I simply assumed that it was a strange 3D object. It certainly seems that it can be interpreted as 4D, although I was unaware that it was explicitly stated.

Comment: @elijaheac I was unaware that *anything* was explicitly stated in the game :) however, I would argue that it's the most "hey look 4d" thing in there.